# Exchange 2010: Disable meeting requests on Room Mailbox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook

In Exchange we would like that only the persons who have permissions to book (meeting)requests.

Without permissions, users cannot add a meeting but they can still send a meeting request, this should be disabled. If also possible, users without permissions should not be able to add the room.

At this very moment, everyone can add the room and send a meeting request. This shows up in the room as "Temporary".

Only accounts who have got the "create items" enabled in permissions should be able to see and add meetings to the room.

Enabling or disabling In- or out-policy meeting requests does not do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

First, "send meeting request to resource mailbox" **is different** with "create items in resource mailbox's calendar". All mailboxes if they has proper permission can create items in resource mailbox's calendar.
Thus, remove all other permission on this resource mailbox, and leave Free/Busy for Default.

Second, to achieve your goal, we need to select "**Enable Resource Booking Attendant...**", then add your VIP account into **Resource In-Policy Requests list**. Figure as below:
[image]

Note: add a **delegate** first.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I tried this and everyone is still able to send meeting requests. Meeting requests should be fully disabled and only meetings should be allowed.